# how to get last 7 days record in mysql if no value in particular day return 0

Tags: mysql

I tried this one but its not working kindly give the solution...

```
select DATE_FORMAT(patient_blood_sugar_record_date,'%a')as Pdate,patient_blood_sugar_Pre_fasting
    from
    (
      select patient_blood_sugar_record_date,patient_blood_sugar_Pre_fasting
      from patient_blood_sugar_record
      where patient_blood_sugar_record_date BETWEEN date_add(curdate(), interval -6 day) AND curdate()
      group by patient_blood_sugar_record_date
      union all
      select curdate(), 0
      union all
      select date_add(curdate(), interval -1 day), 0
      union all
      select date_add(curdate(), interval -2 day), 0
      union all
      select date_add(curdate(), interval -3 day), 0
      union all
      select date_add(curdate(), interval -4 day), 0
      union all
      select date_add(curdate(), interval -5 day), 0
      union all
      select date_add(curdate(), interval -6 day), 0
    ) x
    group by patient_blood_sugar_record_date
    order by patient_blood_sugar_record_date;
```

Comment: Can you add some sample and data and expected output

Comment: sno patient_id patient_blood_sugar_record_date  patient_blood_sugar_Pre_fasting  patient_blood_sugar_Post_fasting 
1 PCH00079 11/05/18 00:00 100 145
2 PCH00079 03/05/18 00:00 120 140
3 PCH00079 04/05/18 00:00 100 110
4 PCH00079 05/05/18 00:00 107 115
5 PCH00079 06/05/18 00:00 150 165
6 PCH00079 07/05/18 00:00 105 128
7 PCH00079 13/06/18 00:00 140 150
8 PCH00079 14/05/18 00:00 114 127
9 PCH00079 15/05/18 00:00 104 110
output             Pdate Patient_blood_sugar_Pre_fasting 
Fri 100
Sat 0
Sun 0
Mon 114
Tue 104
Wed 0
Thu 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It has LEFT JOIN which will give your desired result.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(f.dts,'%a') as Pdate,ifnull(patient_blood_sugar_Pre_fasting,0) patient_blood_sugar_Pre_fasting 
from (select curdate() dts
    union all
    select date_add(curdate(), interval -1 day)
    union all
    select date_add(curdate(), interval -2 day)
    union all
    select date_add(curdate(), interval -3 day)
    union all
    select date_add(curdate(), interval -4 day)
    union all
    select date_add(curdate(), interval -5 day)
    union all
    select date_add(curdate(), interval -6 day)) f
left join
    (select date_format(patient_blood_sugar_record_date,'%a') patient_blood_sugar_record_date,
            min(patient_blood_sugar_Pre_fasting) patient_blood_sugar_Pre_fasting
      from patient_blood_sugar_record
      where patient_blood_sugar_record_date BETWEEN date_add(curdate(), interval -6 day) AND curdate()
      group by date_format(patient_blood_sugar_record_date,'%a')
    ) x
on DATE_FORMAT(f.dts,'%a') = patient_blood_sugar_record_date
order by patient_blood_sugar_record_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please this below sample:--

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_column >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY )

Comment: in  last 7 days no record in db means return the 0 value for particular day     eg: i need  output  like this                                                                                                                                                                                             Fri 100
Sat 0
Sun 0
Mon 114
Tue 104
Wed 0
Thu 0

Comment: SELECT *, DAYNAME(created_at) as dayname, count(id) as totalrecords FROM table WHERE date_column >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY ) GROUP BY dayname

this should work but will not return 0 records.